# Can't update hidden field through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, onselect

I am dealing with the following coding problem which is frustrating me as I think it should be straight forward.  Here is the code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="color" value="red"/>

document.getElementById("color").value="blue"
```

I have a secondary javascript file which listens to an onselect event when a new field is selected.

It does then read the value of the `color` element such as `document.getElementById("color").value` and does something with it.

If I basically hard code the value of the hidden field color through HTML the secondary javascript is able to read the value of the `color` element but when I set it through the JS above it is not.

Should be straight forward but for some reason it's not setting the value as it seems.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code in your answer?

Comment: I tried it strips it out, it's in my original message but all there is this: <input type="hidden" id="color" value="red"/> before the java script tag

Comment: perhaps a jsfiddle and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: ok i am new to this jsfiddle, but here it is :https://jsfiddle.net/7tacLpw1/  it is not running there but i don't exactly know how you need to input.  But hopefully you get the picture .

Comment: See here: https://jsfiddle.net/7tacLpw1/2/ <-- Works. What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, this work, but the example I gave is very simplistic, this is in some client code with way more going on, but i can't paste it here the whole thing due to privacy regulations.  I will dig for some concrete error messages.  However I was wondering if there is any limitations in terms of where the java script lives in relation to the HTML document that could prevent the setting of the value and such

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine, could you inspect console for errors?

```js
document.getElementById("color").value = "blue";
var theColor = document.getElementById("color").value;
document.write("Hidden color is: <strong style='color:" + theColor + "'>" + theColor + "</strong>");
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="color" value="red" />
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work, but as conveyed in my previous response, I just made the script simplistic, it's not the full code of the page which contains jsp, js, and html.  So I need to know if document.getElement(ById) called in any java script segment actually can access the html element.  So are there any instances where the java script (due to location or something else) cannot access the dOM element or anything to that effect?

Answer (score 1):

Oh darn, it was a missing semicolon after document.getElementById("color").value = "blue"  that seems to have been the culprit.

Didn't think JS was so sensitive about this.

Unbelievable how much time I am still able to waste on a missed semicolon after all these years :).

Thanks everyone for your input.
Bob

Answer (score 0):

It's old question
But I thought If any one still looking for the answer , here it is

You can try `$('input[name="NameOfField"]').val('value');` This will work for sure.

When we try to change value of Hidden field at the time of submitting form it didn't update value because DOM has already detached the ID from the input parameter but name is still there because name is going to be passed in form.

If anyone find this useful and they do not have to work for lot hours for a simple solution :)